# Incomming connections have Docker host's IP address instead of the source's real IP when binding host's port to Docker container

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, docker

I am running some services on some different Docker containers. As a simple example:

```
docker run -it -p 123:123/udp ubuntu /bin/bash
```

this `-p 123:123/udp` causes that all incomming connections to my container to have the IP address of Docker container's **host and NOT the source's real IP** (I don't know if it is important to mention that I am using **udp**).

How can I make the incomming connections to have their real source IP address?

Answer (score 0):

That's because docker uses nat by default for networking.
You should start your docker in bridge mode. See [docker bridge](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/networking/#bridge-building)

Comment: Docker starts with bridge mode in default (in my case it is already in default), and yes I know it uses NAT when binding any port, but I am asking how can I go around that. Your answer has doesn't bring any usefuly infos about my question and it is wrong somehow. I don't want to vote it down, change or delete it.